# Oracle determine tablespace name from id

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Oracle 11.2.0.3.0
I am trying to create a graph with historical database size information. The table `dba_hist_tbspc_space_usage` is clearly the one to use however as shown in this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_4064.htm) this table has a TABLESPACE_ID.

Can someone tell me how to find a mapping between tablespace_id and tablespace_name? I tried querying in all_tablespaces but there is no id. However I can see that it is somehow the #rownum (?)

Is there a correct way to find the mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tablespace Id is present in `v$tablespace` view (`TS#` column).

You can refer more about it from [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2156.htm#REFRN30277)

Cheers!!